# Extracting text from a child node within an <a> tag through xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have some data-scraping code intended to pull both the image url and the name of the image (located in the a tag). The code as its written looks like this:

```
BASE = 'http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/'

f = open 'http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/archivepix.html'
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f.read)
html_doc.xpath('//b//a')[0..10].each do |element|
  imgurl = BASE + element.attributes['href'].value
  imgname = element.attributes['innerText']
  puts imgname
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(imgurl).read)
  doc.xpath('//p//a//img').each do |elem|
    small_img = BASE + elem.attributes['src'].value
    puts small_img
  end
end
```

When I run that program I get this output:

```
http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/twolines_yen_960.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/perseids_vangaal_960.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/phas_jpl_960.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/m74_hubble_960.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/tafreshiIMG_4098Trail-s900.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/Albrechtsberg_Perseid2012-08-12_voltmer900.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/ngc3370_hst_900.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/auroraemeteors_boardman_1770.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/cone_noajgendler_960.jpg

http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/image/1308/ioplus_galileo_960.jpg
```

The lines in between the links is where I expect the name of the image to appear (for example: "Moonset from Taiwan" for the first image). I have a feeling the reason I cannot get the name to appear is because it is a child node and I am not accessing it. Does anyone know how I should alter the imgname variable to return the image name?

Comment: Try imgname = element.value The text inside of the <a> tags isn't really an attribute.

Comment: Doesn't work, the method ".value" is undefined. Paul T's solution got the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
html_doc.xpath('//b//a')[0..10].each do |element|
  imgurl = BASE + element.attributes['href'].value
  #imgname = element.attributes['innerText']
  imgname = element.content
  puts imgname
  ...
end
```

`element.text` or `element.inner_text` should provide the same output in your case